# angularjs basic todo example refuses to work

Tags: angularjs, pug

I have the following page I am working on (it is taken from the official angularjs todo example page)

```
doctype 5
html(ng-app)
  head
    title myapp

  body
    div#header-wrapper(ng-controller='PhotosCtrl')
      div.col-wrap#header
        div.col-2.offset-1: div.fixed-height#logo
      div.col-wrap.padded#divisor Welcome

    div.col-wrap.center
      div.col-19#main
        div.item(ng-repeat='photo in photos')
          p.desc(ng-model='photo.desc')

    script(type='text/javascript', src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.5/angular.min.js')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='/js/app.js')


//app.js

function PhotosCtrl($scope){
  $scope.photos =     [
  { url:"http://example.comimage.jpg", desc:"this is a picture" },
  { url:"http://example.comimage.jpg", desc:"this is a picture" },
];
};
```

but nothing is showing in my #main div. Any idea why?

Comment: I think you only need to do {{photo.desc}} & not ng-model

Comment: the problem is that if I do inspect element, there are no divs inside my ng-repeat

Comment: @johnsmith What do you expect to see? pictures?